# Android swipe keyboard with low memory (RAM) usage

Tags: android, optimization, virtual-keyboard

I'm looking for an Android keyboard for older Android devices that have limited RAM.  The only feature that is required is that it *must* support swiping to enter words.

Ideally, it should use no more than 25MB of RAM when running.  Less is better.  A little more is acceptable.

Any price is fine, but [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) is preferred.

The devices will be running Android KitKat.